# How to find the index of an HTML list item in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am coding a ASP.NET MVC application and I have an HTML unordered list generating in my view, which is dynamic and each list item generates with a button, for me to be able to use the button for my intended purposes I need to be able to figure out which button belongs to which list item. So I basically need to be able to find the list index of the specific button which I pressed. I am just wondering how I would go about doing this, is it possible to do it using c# in my controller or do I need to use javascript or jquery then pass that to my controller.

Comment: If you using foreach loop in your view you can get ID in each controller, @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { @id = item.autoID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" })    and access in controller public ActionResult MethodName(int id)